# Return navigation property within join query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In building a patient appointment application I need to return patients with its navigation property `patientDetails` while those returned match a `sessionId` that is not directly deduced from the patient but rather from a series of other navigation properties. This in itself is not difficult, like plain SQL joins can be used, it's just that my navigation property `patientDetails` is never included.

The include path is correct, in case anyone asks.

```
using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
{
    List<tblPatient> res = (from s in db.tblSessions
                            join b in db.tblBookings on s.id equals b.sessionId
                            join r in db.tblReferrals on b.referralId equals r.id
                            join a in db.tblAttendanceStatus on b.attendanceStatus equals a.id
                            join p in db.tblPatients.Include("tblPatientDetail") on r.patientId equals p.id
                            join pd in db.tblPatientDetails on p.patientDetailsId equals pd.id
                            where s.id == id
                            select p).ToList();

    return res;
}
```

It appears to make no difference whether or not I include the `.include`.

What have I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Includes are ignored when you use `join` or `group by`. You can change your query to use `where` instead

```
List<tblPatient> res = (from p in db.tblPatients.Include("tblPatientDetail")
                        where 
                            (from s in db.tblSessions
                             join b in db.tblBookings on s.id equals b.sessionId
                             join r in db.tblReferrals on b.referralId equals r.id
                             join a in db.tblAttendanceStatus on b.attendanceStatus equals a.id
                             where r.patientId == p.id
                             where s.id == id
                             select 1).Any()
                         select p).ToList()
```